# Display index of an array with a delay of 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I tried to keep timeout but it doesn't work. I am sending array and expecting array index with 3 sec delay.

```
function displayIndex(arr){ // array as input
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
        SetTimeout(function(){
            console.log(i); // always returns 4
        },3000);
    }
}

displayIndex([10,20,30,40])
```

update:

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40];
function displayIndex(arr){ // array as input
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
    setTimeout(function () {
      var currentI = i; //Store the current value of `i` in this closure
      console.log(currentI);
    }, 3000);
  }
}

displayIndex(arr); // still prints all 4.
```

Also, tried

```
arr.forEach(function(curVal, index){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(index);
  },3000);
}); // prints 0 1 2 3 but I do not see 3 secs gap between each display, rather one 3 sec delay before everything got displayed.
```

Comment: `setTimeout` instead of `SetTimeout` JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
function displayIndex(arr){ // array as input
    var i=0; 
    var current;
    run=setInterval(function(){ // set function inside a variable to stop it later
        if (i<arr.length) { 
            current=arr[i];  // Asign i as vector of arr and put in a variable 'current'
            console.log(current); 
            i=i+1;  // i increasing
        } else {
            clearInterval(run); // This function stops the setInterval when i>=arr.lentgh
        }
    },3000);    
}
displayIndex([10,20,30,40]);
```

**1st:** If you use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` function inside a `for` that's a problem 'couse all this are loops ways (the first two are loops with time intervals). Aaand `setTimeout` just run code inside once.

*Note:* `setInterval` need a function to stop it `clearInterval`, so that's why i put an `if` inside.

**2nd:** You are not setting `currentI` or `i` like a vector of `arr` operator. When you run an array the format is: `arr[currentI]`, for example.

**Doubts?**

Answer (score 0):

`SetTimeout` should be `setTimeout`.  It's case-sensitive.

You're setting 4 timeouts all at once.  Since you're incrementing the value of `i` every loop, it's going to be `4` at the end of the loop.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps you wanted this?

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var currentI = i; //Store the current value of `i` in this closure
  console.log(currentI);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's behaving unexpectedly:

Case 1: In the first snippet, `setTimeout()` is adding the functions to the Event Queue to be executed after main thread has no more code left to execute. The `i` variable was passed as reference and, so the last modified value gets printed on each call since, it was passed by reference.

Case 2: In this case, since you are passing  4 explicit references, the values are different but, the execution order will same ( I.e., synchronous and instantaneous).

Reason: `setTimeout()` function always pushes the function passed to the queue to be executed with the `delay` acting as a minimum guarantee that it will run with the delayed interval. However, if there is code in the queue before the function or, any other code in the main thread, the delay will be longer.

Workaround: If you do not to implement blocking behaviour in code, I would suggest using an analogue of `process.hrtime()` for browser ( there should be a timing method on the `window` object and, write a `while` loop that explicitly loops until a second has elapsed.

Suggestion: I am somewhat confused as to why you need such blocking in code?

Comment: The reasoning is helpful, I don't need anything specific to blocking code, but I am just trying this algorithm using javascript and could not figure it out until @gabad 's sol. I guess your suggestion consists of nodejs as well. will check. ty.